# How to fix Django N+1 problem when you need to get data from a set of objects

Tags: django, orm

I created a function and I wrote a query that results in N+1 Problem how to fix it

code

```py
sponsors = CustomUser.objects.filter(user_type = 2, is_deleted = False)
for s in sponsors:
    s.sponsor_detail = Sponsor.objects.get_or_create(user = s, is_deleted = False)
```

Comment: Please share your `CustomUser` and `Sponsor` model.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if you included the models, but I guess `sponsor_details` is a ForeignKey. In this case you should use `select_related`:

```py
sponsors = (CustomUser.objects
                      .filter(user_type = 2, is_deleted = False)
                      .select_related('sponsor_detail'))
```